# I am trying to run my docker but i'm getting this error

Tags: python, docker, build, dockerfile

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

ADD main.py .
ADD safe.py .

RUN pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

CMD [ "python", "./main.py", "safe" ]
```

this is the error I'm getting when I run my docker

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: ".": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: Is the `main.py` and `safe.py` in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: yes, they are both in the same directory, I'm creating a bot so the main.py is the main file and the safe.py is for the API key

Comment: Can you try `COPY` instead of `ADD`? I think `COPY` is what you want.

Comment: What are the exact commands you're running that produce that error?  `ADD` vs. `COPY` shouldn't make a difference here (though `COPY` is usually preferable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `ADD` to `COPY` seems to have fixed it.